# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) return different Case on windows 7 Embedded Standard

Tags: .net, windows

We have a C# program that calls:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

On a machine with Windows 7 Professional we get a lower case `c` drive - `c:\\...`

On another machine with Windows 7 Embedded Standard we get an upper case `c` drive - `C:\\...`

**We would prefer keeping the code as is.**

Is there a system / registry / other way to get the lower case output on the latter machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the .ToLower() method to the end of it.

Example:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles).ToLower();
```

Comment: Thanks, We would prefer keeping the code as is, and are looking for a windows modification that could solve the problem.